# how target[y == l] = label work is labeling make_blobs dataset in pytorch tutorial?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset, pytorch, labeling

I am learning PyTorch with this blog: [PyTorch Introduction to Neural Network] (https://medium.com/biaslyai/pytorch-introduction-to-neural-network-feedforward-neural-network-model-e7231cff47cb)
 I found this piece of code confusing:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
def blob_label(y, label, loc): # assign labels
    target = numpy.copy(y)
    for l in loc:
        target[y == l] = label
    return target
x_train, y_train = make_blobs(n_samples=40, n_features=2, cluster_std=1.5, shuffle=True)
x_train = torch.FloatTensor(x_train)
y_train = torch.FloatTensor(blob_label(y_train, 0, [0]))
y_train = torch.FloatTensor(blob_label(y_train, 1, [1,2,3]))
x_test, y_test = make_blobs(n_samples=10, n_features=2, cluster_std=1.5, shuffle=True)
x_test = torch.FloatTensor(x_test)
y_test = torch.FloatTensor(blob_label(y_test, 0, [0]))
y_test = torch.FloatTensor(blob_label(y_test, 1, [1,2,3]))
```

how exactly is `target[y == l] = label` working in here? 
how this line of code assigns 1s and 0s to the data?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Boolean or “mask” index arrays see [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) for more

```py
>>> y = torch.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> y
tensor([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]])
>>> target = np.copy(y)
```

so, `target[y == l] = label`
`y == l` give us boolean array like (if `l = 0`)

```py
>>> y == 0
tensor([[ True, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]])
```

and we can access and assign value using boolean array `y == 0`

```py
>>> target[y == 0]
array([0], dtype=int64)

>>> target[y == 0] = 999
>>> target
array([[999,   1,   2],
       [  3,   4,   5],
       [  6,   7,   8]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you!